# Codeigniter Show Marker on Custom Map

Tags: php, codeigniter, dictionary

I'm having problem in showing markers on the MAP...

I am working on Mapping website. I am able to show multiple markers USING Google MAP.

But now I need to have a CUSTOM MAP. I have a Picture of the MAP but how can I show the marker there.
Look at my Google Map

See below map:

[image]

Please guys help me. How can i show markers on a Custom Map.

Comment: Check example [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple) how to add custom layer to your map. Everything regarding markers remains the same.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But do u have integration for codeigniter?